# How do I get the max ID with Linq to Entity?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a table User which has an identity column `UserID`, now what is the correct Linq to Entity line of code that would return me the max `UserID`?

I've tried:

```
using (MyDBEntities db = new MyDBEntities())
{
    var User = db.Users.Last();
    // or
    var User = db.Users.Max();

    return user.UserID;
}
```

but `Last` and `Max` don't seem to be supported.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Do that like this

```
db.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.UserId).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Does somebody know the performance of this solution compared to the Max(u => u.userId) solution?

Comment: I'm not sure about it but IMHO Max is more performant than Order, since Max is O(n) and Sort implies some algorithm to sort, which is way bigger than O(n).

Answer (score 121):

try this

```
int intIdt = db.Users.Max(u => u.UserId);
```

**Update:**

If no record then generate exception using above code try this

```
int? intIdt = db.Users.Max(u => (int?)u.UserId);
```

Comment: Thanks it's helpful for me int? intIdt = db.Users.Max(u => (int?)u.UserId);

Comment: Is it just me or this style is more readable than Jonas Kongslund's answer?

Comment: @BornToCode It depends on what you're actually trying to do. This solution answer the question (it gets the max id), whereas Jonas Kongslund's answer returns the object with the max id.

Comment: Most eloquent answer!

Comment: Jonas's OrderByDecending method is slightly faster than using Max - 14ms / 11ms

Answer (score 14):

```
var max = db.Users.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(r => r == null ? 0 : r.ModelID);
```

when there are no records in db it would return 0 with no exception.

Comment: r => r?.ModelId ?? 0 - shortcut in new C#

Answer (score 12):

NisaPrieto

```
Users user = bd.Users.Where(u=> u.UserAge > 21).Max(u => u.UserID);
```

will not work because MAX returns the same type of variable that the field is so in this case is an INT not an User object.

Answer (score 3):

In case if you are using the `async` and `await` feature, it would be as follows:

```
User currentUser = await db.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.UserId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that none of these answers will work if the key is a varchar since it is tempting to use MAX in a varchar column that is filled with "ints".

In a database if a column e.g. "Id" is in the database 1,2,3, 110, 112, 113, 4, 5, 6
Then all of the answers above will return 6.

So in your local database everything will work fine since while developing you will never get above 100 test records, then, at some moment during production you get a weird support ticket. Then after an hour you discover exactly this line "max" which seems to return the wrong key for some reason....

(and note that it says nowhere above that the key is INT...) (and if happens to end up in a generic library...)

So use:

Users.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id.Length).ThenByDescending(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score -2):

The best way to get the id of the entity you added is like this:

```
public int InsertEntity(Entity factor)
{
    Db.Entities.Add(factor);
    Db.SaveChanges();
    var id = factor.id;
    return id;
}
```