# How can I find the maximum value in a List using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list:

```
public static List<PhraseModel> phraseList;
```

Where the PhraseModel class looks like this:

```
public class PhraseModel
{
    public string PhraseId { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }
    public string PhraseNum { get; set; }

}
```

How can I find the maximum value of PhraseNum using LINQ

apologies to those that made the comments. PhraseNum is always an  int number but in a string field.  It was set to string because of the way it's read from Excel

Comment: how do you know phraseNum will be a number or a decimal? he has declared it as a string

Comment: Please, provide some *examples*. What is `PhraseNum`, if it's an integer value, why it's of type `string`?

Comment: Do you mean "maximum value" in terms of alphabetical order, or is `PhraseNum` going to always be a number? Or is `PhraseNum` a mixture of alphanumeric characters that you want to sort in a "natural order", that is, A2 comes BEFORE A10?

Comment: How to find max from string? do you want to get based on `string with max length`? or `PhraseNum` is a numeric value? if it is an numeric value then provide change data type of that property or provide us some input data

Comment: Another question: Do you simply want the maximum value of `PhraseNum`? You don't need the associated `PhraseModel` object that contains the maximum?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the max ID with Linq to Entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315946/how-do-i-get-the-max-id-with-linq-to-entity)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq has a Max extension method. Try like:

```
phraseList.Max(x=>int.Parse(x.PhraseNum));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use  `.Max()` from Linq. Here you don't need `Select()`

```
int result = phraseList.Max(x => int.Parse(x.PhraseNum));
Console.WriteLine(result); //max PhraseNum from list
```

To avoid exception you can use `int.TryParse()` mentioned by @haldo

Like,

```
//This is C# 7 Out variable feature. 
int result = phraseList.Max(p => int.TryParse(p.PhraseNum, out int phraseNumInt) ? phraseNumInt: int.MinValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TryParse` instead of `Parse` to avoid exception if there's a chance `PhraseNum` is not an int.

```
int tmp;
var max = phraseList.Max(p => int.TryParse(p.PhraseNum, out tmp) ? tmp : int.MinValue);
```

If you're using C# 7.0 or above you can use the following syntax with inline variable declaration inside the `TryParse`:

```
var max = phraseList.Max(p => int.TryParse(p.PhraseNum, out int tmp) ? tmp : int.MinValue);
```

Or without the `TryParse`:

```
var max = phraseList.Max(p => int.Parse(p.PhraseNum));
```

Answer (score 1):

**This Code Return 8**

```
PhraseModel phraseModel = new PhraseModel() { PhraseNum = "5" };
phraseList.Add(phraseModel);
PhraseModel phraseModel2 = new PhraseModel() { PhraseNum = "3" };
phraseList.Add(phraseModel2);
PhraseModel phraseModel3 = new PhraseModel() { PhraseNum = "4" };
phraseList.Add(phraseModel3);
PhraseModel phraseModel4 = new PhraseModel() { PhraseNum = "8" };
phraseList.Add(phraseModel4);

int number;

var maxPhraseNumber = phraseList.Select(n => int.TryParse(n.PhraseNum, out number) ? number : 0).Max();
```